# Mixed Nash Equilibrium of cyclic game of order 4.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am looking at a symmetric zero-sum game with 4 strategies and the following payoff matrix that has no pure Nash Equilibrium since it forms a circulant graph.$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$I entered the game in a state of the art calculator  ([bimatrix solver](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/%7Erahul/bimatrix_solver/), by Avis, Rosenberg, Savani, and von Stengel) and obtained the result as follows: $$p_1=0.5,\quad p_2=0,\quad p_3=0.5,\quad p_4=0,\quad q_1=0.5,\quad q_2=0,\quad q_3=0.5,\quad q_4=0 $$
$$p_1=0.5,\quad p_2=0,\quad p_3=0.5,\quad p_4=0,\quad q_1=0,\quad q_2=0.5,\quad q_3=0,\quad q_4=0.5 $$
$$p_1=0,\quad p_2=0.5,\quad p_3=0,\quad p_4=0.5,\quad q_1=0.5,\quad q_2=0,\quad q_3=0.5,\quad q_4=0 $$
$$p_1=0,\quad p_2=0.5,\quad p_3=0,\quad p_4=0.5,\quad q_1=0,\quad q_2=0.5,\quad q_3=0,\quad q_4=0.5 $$ What I do not understand is why the mixed strategy with all strategies played with probabilities $\frac{1}{4}$ not a MNE for this game? Is the calculator missing some solutions or am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't it the case that if you have two equilibria in a two-player zero-sum game, then any convex combination of those equilibria is also an equilibrium?

Comment: How do you say that the strategy in question is not an equilibrium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter your bimatrix in the solver, you get the following result:

```
4 x 4 Payoff matrix A:

   0   1   0  -1
  -1   0   1   0
   0  -1   0   1
   1   0  -1   0



4 x 4 Payoff matrix B:

   0  -1   0   1
   1   0  -1   0
   0   1   0  -1
  -1   0   1   0

EE = Extreme Equilibrium, EP = Expected Payoff

Decimal Output

  EE  1  P1:  (1)  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  EP=  0.0  P2:  (1)  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  EP=  0.0
  EE  2  P1:  (1)  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  EP=  0.0  P2:  (2)  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  EP=  0.0
  EE  3  P1:  (2)  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  EP=  0.0  P2:  (1)  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  EP=  0.0
  EE  4  P1:  (2)  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  EP=  0.0  P2:  (2)  0.000000  0.500000  0.000000  0.500000  EP=  0.0

Rational Output

  EE  1  P1:  (1)  1/2    0  1/2    0  EP=  0  P2:  (1)  1/2    0  1/2    0  EP=  0
  EE  2  P1:  (1)  1/2    0  1/2    0  EP=  0  P2:  (2)    0  1/2    0  1/2  EP=  0
  EE  3  P1:  (2)    0  1/2    0  1/2  EP=  0  P2:  (1)  1/2    0  1/2    0  EP=  0
  EE  4  P1:  (2)    0  1/2    0  1/2  EP=  0  P2:  (2)    0  1/2    0  1/2  EP=  0

Connected component 1:
{1, 2}  x  {1, 2}
```

I believe the way to read this is the strategy $1$ is given by $s_1 =(0.5,0,0.5,0)$ and the strategy $2$ is given by $s_2 = (0,0.5,0,0.5)$.

The very last line says there is a "connected component", and in this case it means that both players playing any convex combination between $s_1$ and $s_2$ is also a Nash equilibrium. In particular, the strategy profile $((0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))$ is a Nash equilibrium.

Comment: I am confused of the meaning of having an infinite number of equilibrium. Does stability matter in those scenarios? I guess I should read on Equilibrium Selection.